# Can't get all xpath elements from dynamic webpage

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, xpath

First time here asking. Hope someone can help me with this, it's driving me crazy !

1. I'm trying to **scrape** a used-car webpage from my country. The data loads when you start to scroll down, so, the first part of the code is for scrolling down and load the webpage.
2. I'm trying to get the link of every car published here, that's why I'm using find_**elements**_by_xpath in the try-except part.

Well, the problem is, the cars are showed up in packs of 11 for every load(scroll down), so the 11 xpaths repeats when scrolling down everytime;

meaning xpaths from

```
"//*[@id='w1']/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"
```

to

```
"//*[@id='w11']/div[1]/div/div[1]/a"
```

##### All libraries are called at the start of the code, don't worry.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time

links = []

url = ('https://buy.olxautos.cl/buscar?VehiculoEsSearch%5Btipo_valor%5D=1&VehiculoEsSearch%5Bprecio_range%5D=3990000%3B15190000')
driver = webdriver.Chrome('')
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height

try:
    zelda = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[@id='w1']/div[1]/div/div[1]/a").get_attribute('href')
    links.append(zelda)
except:
    pass

print(links)
```

So the **expected** output of this code would be something like this:

```
['link_car_1', 'link_car_12', 'link_car_23', '...']
```

But when I run this code, it returns an empty list. But when I run it with find_**element**_by_xpath returns the first link, what am I doing wrong , I just can't figure it out !!.

Thanks!

Comment: `All libraries are called at the start of the code, don't worry.` - the point is to include all necessary ones, to run the provided code and reproduce the problem, in the question.

Comment: @QHarr Added, should I put it like an update?, or just edit like I've done ?

Comment: Like you did was perfect. +

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get only one link because the XPATH is not the same for all the links. you can use bs4 to extract links by using the driver page source as shown below.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import lxml

links = []

url = ('https://buy.olxautos.cl/buscar?VehiculoEsSearch%5Btipo_valor%5D=1&VehiculoEsSearch%5Bprecio_range%5D=3990000%3B15190000')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = Path)
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(5)

SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME = 3

# Get scroll height
last_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

while True:
    # Scroll down to bottom

    page_source_ = driver.page_source
    
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

    # Wait to load page
    time.sleep(SCROLL_PAUSE_TIME)

    # Calculate new scroll height and compare with last scroll height
    new_height = driver.execute_script("return document.body.scrollHeight")

    #use BeautifulSoup to extract links
    sup = BeautifulSoup(page_source_, 'lxml')
    sub_ = sup.findAll('div', {'class': 'owl-item active'})
    
    for link_ in sub_:
        link = link_.find('a', href= True)
        #link = 'https://buy.olxautos.cl' + link #if needed (adding prefix)
        links.append(link['href'])
    
    if new_height == last_height:
        break
    last_height = new_height
    
print('>> Total length of list : ', len(links))
print('\n',links)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much !, I was so tilted yesterday I couldn't see another way around. This is the perfect answer.